# O que é uma pergunta mesclada?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Hoje me deparei pela primeira vez com [uma pergunta mesclada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241620/formatar-valor-em-dinheiro-enquanto-digita-com-javascript-puro?noredirect=1&lq=1) e ela possui uma referência para [essa questão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) (em inglês). Achei pertinente criar uma pergunta similar aqui.

[image: Exemplo de aviso de uma pergunta mesclada. A mensagem é "Mesclada com Formatar moeda brasileira em JavaScript".]

- O que é uma pergunta mesclada?
- Quando uma pergunta deve ser mesclada?
- Quem pode mesclar perguntas? Como eu posso sinalizar para isso?
- O que acontece com a pergunta após ser mesclada?
- Há mais algum detalhe importante sobre perguntas mescladas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que é uma pergunta mesclada?

Duas ou mais perguntas viraram uma só. É como duplicata, só que junta seu conteúdo (as respostas) com a outra.

> Quando uma pergunta deve ser mesclada?

Quando for claramente a mesma pergunta, não há diferença alguma, mesmo que mínima.

> Quem pode mesclar perguntas? Como eu posso sinalizar para isso?

Moderadores diamante podem.

Em geral a marca de duplicata é suficiente, na teoria. Mas em geral é difícil conseguir mesclar e moderadores costumam deixar passar. Então uma sinalização personalizada pode ser útil, se tiver muita certeza que dá para mesclar. Não é para abusar disso.

Perguntas que não tem respostas são mais fáceis para mesclar com outra que tem respostas.

> O que acontece com a pergunta após ser mesclada?

Só junta todas respostas. Por isso que precisa ser muito igual. todas respostas tem que continuar fazendo sentido quando junta.

> Há mais algum detalhe importante sobre perguntas mescladas?

O mais importante é que dá menos certo do que parece.

Ao mesmo tempo acho que deveria usar mais, ficou sem tradição.